# Does the function $\frac{z^2}{z+1}$ maps the unit disk to $\mathbb C$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Does the function $\frac{z^2}{z+1}$  maps the unit disk to $\mathbb C$?

My guess is yes. But how to prove this, if it is true? My strategy is given $y \in \mathbb C$, I need to solve $z^2-yz-y=0$, but how am I be able to ensure that it will have a root in the unit disk?

Comment: What happens near $-1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try $y:=-2$. Then you have to solve $z^2+2z+2=0$, which has the solutions $z_\pm=-1\pm i$, both of absolute value $\sqrt{2}>1$. It follows that the given function does not take the value $-2$ in the unit disk.